# javascript setDate -1 month off by 30 days changing from July 31 to Aug 30

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have the following code bringing my head to crazy.

```
var forDt = new Date("2017-07-31"+ "T09:00:00.000");
    var workDt = new Date();
    workDt.setDate(forDt.getDate() - 1);
    date_prev = workDt.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

Today is August 1st. I clicked a `Prev` button twice and `datePrev` changed from `July 31` to `August 30.`

Could someone help and tell me what went wrong please? Seems like `setDate()` set `31-1=30`, but without updating the month. Is there anyway to fix it please?

Thanks guys.=)

Comment: Note that you are using a string that will be interpreted as local, but then using *toISOString* which will return UTC+0000 so may differ by a day, depending on the host timezone offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `new Date()` due to which `workDt` will refer to the current date of the system.

```js
var forDt = new Date("2017-07-31" + "T09:00:00.000");
var workDt = new Date(forDt.getTime());
workDt.setDate(forDt.getDate() - 1);
date_prev = workDt.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

console.log(date_prev);

workDt.setDate(workDt.getDate() - 1);
date_prev = workDt.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

console.log(date_prev);
```

By setting workDt using `new Date(forDt.getTime())`, you make a copy of the date you want to reduce, and after setting the day of the month back, you'll get the right answer